# Counting how many lottery tickets have $5$ out of $7$ numbers right

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> A lottery ticket has $7$ numbers from $1$ to $48$. There are $7$ winning numbers. How many possible tickets have exactly $5$ of the winning numbers?

So what I know so far is there are ${48 \choose 7}$ for total combinations which is $73629072$.

${7 \choose 5}$ is $21$, but I'm not sure what is left to do.

Comment: Are the numbers on the tickets in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

If repetitions are not allowed, then you can choose the  $5$ winning numbers in $7\choose5$ ways and the remaining 2 non-winning numbers can be chosen from the $41$ non-winning numbers in $41\choose2$ ways , for a total of $${7\choose5} \times {41 \choose 2 }$$ ways( If  the order of the two numbers makes a difference ) and half that (use permutations for the choice of the two cards from the remaining $41$ non-winners) , for a total of $8610$.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit it now.

Comment: that seems like it should be right after I saw it, but it wasn't {41 \ choose 2} = 820 and 820 * 21 = 17220 and that was sadly not correct.

Comment: @Leo: are repetitions allowed? Does the order matter?

Comment: A lottery ticket has 7 numbers from 1 to 48.
How many possible tickets are there?

The lottery agency gives 7 winning numbers. How many possible tickets have exactly 5 of the winning numbers?

up there is the question. 

I think since it's a lottery you can't use the numbers over again, but order could matter the question didn't say specifically.

Comment: @Leo You're repeating yourself. So do you know for sure if repetitions allowed, and if order matters? Yes/no, yes/no. Do you have the answer available? If so, we could use that to infer the desired interpretation of the question.

Comment: I understand, but , let {$a,b,c,d,e$}  be the 5 winning numbers. Is the combination {$a,b,c,d,e, n_1,n_2$} equal {$a,b,c,d,e, n_2, n_1$}?  If yes, the result would be half of what I got, i.e., 8610.

Comment: I don't have the answer available. I know that you cannot use the same number over again and order does not matter. 

EDIT: Order may matter. The question doesn't say. I thought his answer was right, so maybe it does.

Comment: @Leo: so how can you tell my answer is wrong if you don't have the answers?

Comment: it's a homework problem that i've been working on for like a hour straight now.

8610 isn't it either. I think your logic makes sense and I have no idea why it isn't correct.

Comment: @hyper teacher said it was right and there was bug with homework. sorry. i thought it looked right when i saw it

Comment: @Leo: no problem, at least we got it.